# Angular single component used multple times on same page and trying to switch focus by JavaScript, the focus is pointing only to the first instance

Tags: angular

Angular single component used multiple times on same page and trying to switch focus using JavaScript. The focus is only pointing to the first instance, not the current component instance.

Component Template

```
<div>
   <input id="hour">
   <input id="min">
   <input id="ampm">
   <input type="button">
   <input type="button"> 
</div>

selector : time-picker
```

For changing focus on different input I am using:

```
setFocus(id){
   document.getElementById(id).focus();
}
```

I am using this component on another component multiple(6) times. like

```
1st   <time-picker>
2nd   <time-picker>
3rd   <time-picker>
4th   <time-picker>
6th   <time-picker>
7th   <time-picker>
```

But the focus is still showing 1st component instance. Is there any other way to access each instance so that I can show the current focus?

Note: I am not using a directive. Now its difficult for me to use directive.

Comment: It sounds like you have a non-unique id. Did you have a look at Angular's `ViewChild` decorator?

Comment: Is there anything without using viewChild. Like dynamic Id creation.. and assigning the focus?